# Wpf localization without additional folders

Tags: wpf, localization, directory, resx

I create a WPF application and want to add several languages for it. Localization is created via resx-files (smth like Labels.resx and Labels.en-US.resx). After project building a new folder **bin\en-US** is created. But the concept is that the application should be represented as the only one EXE-file.

So the question: is it possible to store all resx-files (default (Labels.resx) and any localized (e.g. Labels.en-US.resx)) inside EXE-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, from Microsoft's site:

> At compile time, Visual Studio first converts the .resx files in a project to binary resource (.resources) files and stores them in a subdirectory of the project's obj directory. Visual Studio embeds any resource files that do not contain localized resources in the main assembly that is generated by the project. If any resource files contain localized resources, Visual Studio embeds them in separate satellite assemblies for each localized culture. It then stores each satellite assembly in a directory whose name corresponds to thelocalized culture. For example, localized English (United States) resources are stored in a satellite assembly in the en-US subdirectory.

Comment: if i want to represent UI in English and  Gujarati(other language) then what is in main assembly?.I have created folder for English "en" and Gujarati ("gu")

Comment: You don't need to create any folder, the folders are created by Visual Studio. I assume we're talking about WPF?

Comment: Is this still the "state of the art" or is there a possibility to integrate them now? I'm using Costura.Fody to include all my dlls but the language dlls are still output in the subfolders.